# How to check free available space in Phonegap iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

I tried this:

```
cordova.exec(win, fail, "File", "getFreeDiskSpace", []);
```

But it always return 0 in iOS.

Comment: Do you running from emulator or from real device?

Comment: and the plugin version?

Comment: I m running from real device. iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 both have same issue. And my phonegap version is 3.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your CDVFile.m in your phonegap with this code:

```
// Returns number of bytes available via callback
- (void)getFreeDiskSpace:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{    
    uint64_t totalSpace = 0;
    uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];

    if (dictionary) {
        NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];
        NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
        totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
    } else {
        //NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %@", [error domain], [error code]);
        NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info");
    }
    NSString* strFreeSpace = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", totalFreeSpace];
    CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:strFreeSpace];

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];

    //return totalFreeSpace;

}
```